# Interactive plots of simplicial complexes

Tags: plot, 3d, plotly, networkx, interactive

I'm attempting to create interactive plots of simplicial complexes [Simplicial Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex)

using the python library plotly. So far, I've only managed to create interactive plots of the underlying graph(the vertices and the edges). This I learned from this: [3d network interactive graphs](https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-network-graph/) However, when the complex has triangles(let's stick to 2-dimensional complexes), I wish to plot those triangles too. I'm not able to find anything regarding this on the internet. Can anyone point me to a source on how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? It's still pretty much impossible to find something about it online

Comment: so far I have not :(